# After update apache2 stops working

Tags: server, updates, apache2, php

when I run `systemctl status apache2.service` I get

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-05-08 16:22:44 CDT; 5s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 1949 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 08 16:22:44 sturtz.ml systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
May 08 16:22:44 sturtz.ml apachectl[1964]: apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.3.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/mo>
May 08 16:22:44 sturtz.ml apachectl[1949]: Action 'start' failed.
May 08 16:22:44 sturtz.ml apachectl[1949]: The Apache error log may have more information.
May 08 16:22:44 sturtz.ml systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 08 16:22:44 sturtz.ml systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 08 16:22:44 sturtz.ml systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I don't understand what is wrong. I upgraded to Ubuntu Server 20.04

Comment: I ran 'a2dismod php7.3' then 'systemctl restart apache2' then 'systemctl start apache2' and now https://sturtz.ml is working again!

Comment: I need to use php7.3